# Should this patent list prior art associated with it?

Tags: prior-art-request

In reference to the patent: [US5795630](https://www.google.com/patents/US5795630)

Should this patent have prior art associated with it? I do not know if the patent exists, but the toy in the following link is the same shape/design as the internal illusion component: http://www.hippie-sticks.com

Does a patent exist to reference as prior similar art?

Comment: You have any proof that hippie sticks existed before 1983?

Comment: I do not, but that is what I am looking for, essentially.

Comment: The design for hippie sticks seems to be too obvious, however, to be granted a patent. Though I am no expert.

Answer (score 1):

The fee status is lapsed on that patent but here is some prior art:

[US5795630 Prior Art](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US5795630#c=0&d1&d2=08%2F19%2F1996&t=1illusion.1transparent%20case.1motorized%20spinning.0mylar.0entertainment%20purposes.0amusement.0motivation.0periodic%20circuit.0free%20space.0observer.)

Also these reference the above patent as prior art:
https://www.google.com/patents/US20050126374
https://www.google.com/patents/US6570078

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the question is clear. Why would you need prior art to an expired patent? The patent seems to have a priority date in the year 1993. It is really hard to find a website that existed before 1993. In fact, while the World Wide Web was invented in 1989, it wasn't until April of 1993 that the software was put in the public domain. That's why there are probably only a few sites in that era. See these URLs - 
https://home.cern/topics/birth-web
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notable_websites_founded_before_1995

Comment: I guess my primary purpose was that I was actually looking for the patent to the hippie sticks. I see many trademarked names of this same device, but never a patent. Been looking for this for years with no luck.